# Best way to process the annotations

Tags: java

I have 3 different kinds of custom annotations. Assume those are Annotation1,Annotation2,Annotation3.

I was applied these 3 annotations to some of the fields in my class. Now I am extracting/getting all the fields which are assigned these 3 annotations. So for that I wrote a method like

```
public List<Field> getAnnotation1Fields(Annotation1 argAnnotation1){
     // Code to extract those fields...
}
```

So for my 3 annotations I need to write 3 different methods like

```
public List<Field> getAnnotation2Fields(Annotation2 argAnnotation2){
     // Code to extract those fields...
}

public List<Field> getAnnotation3Fields(Annotation3 argAnnotation3){
     // Code to extract those fields...
}
```

In the above methods the Extraction logic is same but the parameter type is different (Argument). Here my question is how can I call these three methods on single annotation...? So that one common method can be called for any type of annotation (Including our custom annotations).

Comment: Are you passing an annotation to that method or an *annotation type*?

Answer (score 0):

Use method generics - You can define a variable type parameter for methods, as well as classes, like so:

```
public <T> List<Field> getAnnotationFields(T argAnnotation) {
  // Get fields with annotation type T
}
```

And then you can call it as easily as:

```
Annotation3 thingy = ...;
getAnnotationFields(thingy); // Extracts fields for Annotation3
```

Comment: `<T extends Annotation>`

Comment: Here I am using Custom annotations. My Custom Annotation has 2 variables. While extracting those fields I need to access those variables. So for that I need to TypeCast with my custom annotation right...? 
So getAnnotationFields(T argAnnotation) I need to type cast to CustomAnn = (CustomAnn)argAnnotation; like this. How can I avoid this type casting step and also need to access those variables. So is there any way to achieve this ...?

Comment: @Amar: You said the extraction logic is always the same, in other words does not depend on your annotation type. Are you mixing up extraction of the annotated elements and using the annotation values?

Comment: Yeah, Because I am building a two maps one is AnnotationsVsField (Here field is a java reflection field) and the second one is my annotation has a type variable so my second map is FieldNameVsType. So for building a second map we need values. So how can I achieve this...?

Comment: @Amar: Please, add these details to your question. Esp. with correct Java code showing the signatures of the resulting objects.

Answer (score 0):

`public List<Field> getAnnotatedFields(java.lang.annotation.Annotation annotation)`

or

`public List<Field> getAnnotatedFields(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType)`

depending on what you have instance (first) or type (second).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with this simple method:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public static List<Field> getAnnotatedFields(Class<?> clazz, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType) {
    Field[] declaredFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    List<Field> annotatedFields = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Field field : declaredFields) {
        if(field.getAnnotation(annotationType) != null)
            annotatedFields.add(field);
    }
    return annotatedFields;
}
```

Usage example:

```
getAnnotatedFields(TestClass.class, Deprecated.class);
```

Comment: Hay Thanq, But Along with this I need some more information. Here I am building a two maps one is AnnotationsVsField (Here field is a java reflection field) and the second one is my annotation has a variable called "type". Here my second map is FieldNameVsType. So for building a second map we need "type" variable values for this I need to type cast with the corresponding annotation right ...? With the above method how can I achieve this feature...?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that’s closer to your needs:

```
static <A extends Annotation> Map<String,A> getField2Annotation(
  Class<?> declaringClass, Class<A> annotationType) {

  Field[] fields=declaringClass.getDeclaredFields();
  Map<String, A> map=Collections.emptyMap();
  for(Field f:fields) {
    A anno=f.getAnnotation(annotationType);
    if(anno!=null) {
      if(map.isEmpty()) map=new HashMap<String, A>();
      map.put(f.getName(), anno);
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
public class Example {
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @interface Foo { String value() default "bar"; }

  @Foo static String X;
  @Foo("baz") String Y;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Foo> map = getField2Annotation(Example.class, Foo.class);
    for(Map.Entry<String,Foo> e:map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(e.getKey()+": "+e.getValue().value());
    }
  }
}
```